# Facebook Fans page, Application and Comments Box

Tags: facebook

The facebook comments plugin require an application ID: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments

1. But currently I only have a fans page, is it a must to create an application in order to use the comments plugin?
2. If I created an application, do I need to link up the fans page and application?

Comment: you want to put your comments plugin in your fan page?! didn't get you there...just create an application get the app ID and follow the instructions in the link you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes you have to create an application.
2. No you do not need to link them up.

Comment: I dont think it is necessary to create a app if u just want to use the comment box, could you give me an example why would i need app when i manage my comment box?